# how to identify a cognito id belongs to a pool using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

Using bellow code i am getting an `OpenID token` for an `IdentityId`.

```
import boto3
cognito_client = boto3.client('cognito-identity')
data = {'IdentityPoolId': identity_pool_id,
        'Logins': logins,
        'TokenDuration': 24 * 60 * 60,
        'IdentityId': identity_id}
cognito_client.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity(
            **data)
```

But i have two `IdentityPoolId`, so i need  to identify proper `IdentityPoolId` for a given `IdentityId`.
Using boto3 library how can i identify a `IdentityId` belongs to a `IdentityPoolId` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have available is just the IdentityId value you would need to use list_identities() function of the Cognito-Identity client to get all of the IDs from a pool and then determine if your ID is part of the pool.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.list_identities

```
import boto3

def getPoolID(boto3Client,PoolIDs,idVal):
    For PoolID in PoolIDs: 
        response = boto3Client.list_identities(IdentityPoolId=PoolID)   
        for ID in response['Identities']:
            if idVal == ID['IdentityId']:
                return PoolID

cognitoClient = boto3.client('cognito-identity')
PoolIDList=['PoolID1','PoolID2'] 
IdentityIdToCheck='Value'
FinalPoolID = getPoolID(cognitoClient,PoolIDList,IdentityIdToCheck)
print FinalPoolID
```

You might need to adjust how you get the response based on the number of IDs in your ID pools, as you may need to paginate through the records